# How to extract all subsection titles from beamer and iterative create commands

Tags: beamer, programming

I want to extract all subsection titles from a beamer presentation to later build a customized table of contents similar to [Links in mindmap as table of contents in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215521/links-in-mindmap-as-table-of-contents-in-beamer). But I would use the iterative built commands where the subsection titles are stored. I think latex should run at least twice.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\AtBeginSubsection{%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
    \expandafter\def\csname Section\thesection subsection\thesubsection\endcsname{\tableofcontents[currentsubsection,hideothersubsections,sectionstyle=hide/hide,subsectionstyle=show/hide]}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{contents of all subsections}

    % The commands below shall be defined 
    \SectionAsubsectionA
    \SectionAsubsectionB
    \SectionBsubsectionA

\end{frame}

\section{section 1}

\subsection{subsection 1.1}

\subsection{subsection 1.2}

\section{section 2}

\subsection{subsection 2.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [The following does what you seem to be after](http://pastebin.com/R5Kabnmh), but I don't get how you'd use it...

Comment: Alternative approaches could be to 1) read the information from the `.toc` file 2) to manipulate the creation of the `.toc` file to already contain the mindmap code or 3) to use the beamer way and modify the definition of `\insertsectionnavigation` and `\insertsubsectionnavigation`.  But I have not enough `tikz`/mindmap knowledge to do either.

Comment: @Werner I would use it to define leafs of the mindmap tree. Per each section, the subsections would be the leafs. With that approach I could use a `\foreach` to build the section and them connect its leafs (wich would be the subsections).

Comment: @cacamailg: I use `\csname` ... `\endcsname` which doesn't throw an error when you make a call to it. However, you may as well define something with `\providecommand` to make sure it exists. Then, I write to the `.aux` which is read in around `\begin{document}`. That allows you to use the defined macros in a similar way to how one would use `\label`s` and `\ref`s.

Comment: @Werner I tried your code, but it didn't work. I was not able to print the subsections name. Can you provide a full answer?

Comment: @cacamailg: Well, yes, that's because you define the `\SectionXSubsectionY` to expand to `\tableofcontents[..]`. That's what I don't understand in your question. Your title suggests you want to retrieve the `\subsection` title, but your question uses `\tableofcontents` as the definition.

Comment: @Werner Well, yes. I want to extract all the subsections names (and possible numbers) in a beamer presentation. So that latter I can build a custom ToC, following, e.g. a mindmap or a table. The idea in the end is to have a possible way to have the sections/subsections that were used in the document stored in a command or via `csname... \endcsname`.

Comment: @cacamailg: Check [this example](http://pastebin.com/R7ci9TbA).

Comment: It gave me an error `Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \global\defA
                 .A{} subsection 1.1{A.A{} subsection 1.1}
`.

Comment: @cacamailg: Sorry, check [this example](http://pastebin.com/1kVee1wB).

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that is missing is the hyperlink. Would it be possible to have it? Furthermore, if you provide the answer here I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the comments from Werner, so all credits shall go to him.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
    \oldsection[#1]{#2}% Call default \section (this also steps the section counter)
    \hypertarget{\csname Section\Alph{section}\endcsname}{}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0=0pt%
        \immediate\write\@auxout%
            {\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}{%
              \arabic{section}{.} #2}}%
            %{\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}{#2}}%
    \else%
        \immediate\write\@auxout%
            {\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}{%
              \arabic{section}{.} #1}}%
            %{\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}{#1}}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{%
    \oldsubsection[#1]{#2}% Call default \subsection (this also steps the subsection counter)
    \hypertarget{\csname Section\Alph{section}subsection\Alph{subsection}\endcsname}{}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0=0pt%
        \immediate\write\@auxout%
            {\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}subsection\Alph{subsection}{%
              \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}{.} #2}}%
            %{\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}subsection\Alph{subsection}{#2}}%
    \else%
        \immediate\write\@auxout%
            {\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}subsection\Alph{subsection}{%
              \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}{.} #1}}%
            %{\string\global\string\def\string\Section\Alph{section}subsection\Alph{subsection}{#1}}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

% Print sections with hyperlinks
\foreach \Idxsec in {A,...,Z}{%
    \ifcsname Section\Idxsec \endcsname
        \xdef\sectionname{\csname Section\Idxsec\endcsname}
        \hyperlink{\sectionname}{\sectionname}\par
    \fi
}

% Print subsections with hyperlinks
\foreach \Idxsec in {A,...,Z}{%
    \foreach \Idxsubsec in {A,...,Z}{%
        \ifcsname Section\Idxsec subsection\Idxsubsec \endcsname
            \xdef\subsectionname{\csname Section\Idxsec subsection\Idxsubsec\endcsname}
            \hyperlink{\subsectionname}{\subsectionname}\par
        \fi
    }
}

% Print sections and subsections with hyperlinks
\foreach \Idxsec in {A,...,Z}{%
    \ifcsname Section\Idxsec \endcsname
        \xdef\sectionname{\csname Section\Idxsec\endcsname}
        \hyperlink{\sectionname}{\sectionname}\par
        \foreach \Idxsubsec in {A,...,Z}{%
            \ifcsname Section\Idxsec subsection\Idxsubsec \endcsname
                \xdef\subsectionname{\csname Section\Idxsec subsection\Idxsubsec\endcsname}
                \hyperlink{\subsectionname}{\subsectionname}\par
            \fi
        }
    \fi
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```