# Read out .toc-file, Customised header in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm writing my own beamer theme, I had some fancy idea to layout my header in beamer class: I progress bar on top and below the sections corresponding to the slides where they start, namely:

```
----------
          Section 1
```

The progress bar is designed as follows:

```
\progressbar{\footerBarHeight}
\dimen0=\textwidth
\multiply\dimen0 by \insertframenumber
\divide\dimen0 by \inserttotalframenumber
\edef\progressbarwidth{\the\dimen0}
\leavevmode%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=.1ex,dp=.1ex]{progress bar}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\progressbarwidth,ht=.1ex,dp=.1ex]{progress bar progress}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
```

So, my idea was to use the data in the .toc-file

```
\beamer@sectionintoc {1}{Section 1}{2}{0}{1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\beamer@subsectionintoc {1}{1}{Subsection 1.1}{7}{0}{1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\beamer@subsectionintoc {1}{2}{Subsection 1.2}{10}{0}{1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\beamer@sectionintoc {2}{Section 2}{13}{0}{2}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\beamer@sectionintoc {3}{Section 3}{22}{0}{3}
```

that provides the page number where the section starts and compare this with (e.g. `\insertframenumber`) to align & print the three section title by `\insertsection`.

My questions:

(1) Can I use this data? Is there any variable already defined in beamer to get the page number of the `@sectionintoc`?

(2) Is there an easier way just to print all three section titles? (Maybe iterate modulo something).

Comment: I think it is easier to work with labels, e.g. exploiting `\getrefnumber` from the `refcount` package (which is loaded most likely anyways, since `beamer` uses `hyperref` by default)

Comment: maybe you can get something useful from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338241/how-to-extract-all-subsection-titles-from-beamer-and-iterative-create-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes, `\insertsectionstartpage`. See the manual page 65.

(2) Yes,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{title of section 1}
\section{title of section 2}
\section{title of section 3}
\section{title of section 4}
\section{title of section 5}
\subsection{title of subsection 5-1}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@endinputifotherversion#1{}
\def\beamer@sectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5{#2;}
\def\beamer@subsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6{}
%\def\beamer@subsubsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{}

\frame{
    \@input{\jobname.toc}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]