# beamer: How to Show \subsubsections in \footline

Tags: beamer

I need to insert `subsubsections` (mind the `subsub`) in `footline` for presentation with `beamer` and `AnnArbor` theme, like `subsection` with `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal`.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Even some people can read French, please, write in English.

Comment: any one have a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution:

You'll have to manually specify at the begin of each subsection how many subsubsections are in this subsection.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{totalsubsub}

\AtBeginSubsubsection[]{\label{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\thesubsubsection}}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \ifnum\thetotalsubsub>0
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\thetotalsubsub}{% 
                \hfill
                \ifnum\i=\thesubsubsection
                    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}
                \else
                    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}
                \fi
                \hyperlink{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\i}{\nameref{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\i}}
            }
            \hfill
            \hspace*{0pt}
        \fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{sub 1}
\setcounter{totalsubsub}{3}

\subsubsection{subsub 1}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 1
\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsub 2}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 2
\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsub 3}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 3
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub 2}
\setcounter{totalsubsub}{0}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

For automatically retrieving the number of subsubsections per subsection the `xcntperchap` package might be helpful. I tried to use it similarly to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303968/36296 but I only managed to get the numbers for the first section.

Comment: thanks samcarter, but i want to insert subsubsection, not subsection, with AnnArbor theme.

Comment: @miloud Which theme do you use?

Comment: Ok, i use AnnArbor theme.